# Convert 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 to null failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query does not work:

```
(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Time,3) IN ('31/12/99') THEN 'NA' ELSE Time END)
```

I get

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: I tried to make the question a little clearer, but I'm not completely sure if I got it right. Please review and revert or edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually *want* `NULL` (rather than `'NA'`), then you probably ought to use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
SELECT NULLIF(time,'99991231')
```

<strike>I'm assuming your SQL Server is configured with a 2-digit year cutoff, such that it interprets the year `99` as `1999`. If you had a different year `99` in mind, change `1999` to what you were thinking of.</strike>

---

Having re-read your title, you're wanting to use the year 9999, not 1999 (nor 2099) - in such a case, you *really* ought to be using four digit years.

---

If `time` might have a time component as well as a date, then `CASE` might be warranted - but it would still be better to do the comparisons as `datetime` values rather than as strings:

```
CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,Time),0) = '99991231' THEN NULL ELSE Time END
```

As @KaR points out - if you want to have the text `'NA'` rather than `NULL`, then you need to convert `Time` to a string - a `CASE` *expression* can only have a single return type, and if it has to choose between `datetime` and `varchar`, it will choose the former.

Comment: *‘If `time` might have a time component as well as a date, then `CASE` might be warranted’* – not sure what you mean there. NULLIF can be used in this case as well: `NULLIF(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,Time),0), '99991231')`. Anyway, it seems unlikely that the `9999-12-31` date would be used with a time component, so your first `NULLIF` seems quite enough.

Comment: @AndriyM - but in that case, the returned value from `NULLIF` would have no time component either - whereas the `CASE`, if it's returning the `time` column, is returning it intact.

Comment: Ah, indeed, in CASE you are returning `time`, not `DATEADD(...)`. You are right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your case query return two different type, which are:

- 'NA' is VarChar and
- [Time] which is a DateTime.

So to fix this you should return [Time] as VarChar type.

Try this code below:

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time], 3) IN ('31/01/12') THEN 'NA' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Time], 3) END
```

Comment: i see, thanks. But, it is not work for '31/12/99', do you know why?

Comment: What error does it throw? I have tried change the date into '31/12/99' and it is working fine. Probably could you sent me the table structure and your complete query.

Answer (score 0):

try below code....

```
declare @t1 table(t1 DATETIME)
insert into @t1(t1)
select '9999-12-31 00:00' UNION ALL
select '01-04-2012 11:20' union all
select '9999-12-31 10:00' 
select case when dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,t1),0) not in('9999-12-31') then t1 end date from @t1
```

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and use the `{}` button - it maintains line breaks and adds syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that has these results:

[Excel Table with two columns, 'Suspend_Started_Date_Time' and 'Suspend_Complete_Date_Time'. All start date times are populated with real  data but some cases are still in suspend so have no suspend complete date time, those have the SQL placeholder date time of 31/12/9999 00:00:00.000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSXqg.png)

If I wanted to replace the value '31/12/9999 00:00:00.000' with todays date & time I would use this syntax:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Suspend_Complete_Date_Time, 112) = '99991231') 
    THEN GETDATE() 
    ELSE Suspend_Complete_Date_Time END 
AS Suspend_Complete_Date_Time
```

If I wanted to replace the same value with NULL I would use this syntax:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Stage_Completed_Date_Time, 112) = '99991231') 
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE Stage_Completed_Date_Time END 
AS Suspend_Complete_Date_Time
```

An example of the complete syntax would look like this:

```
    SELECT 
        Case_ID, 
        Stage_Started_Date_Time AS Suspend_Started_Date_Time, 
        CASE 
           WHEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Stage_Completed_Date_Time, 112) = '99991231') THEN NULL 
       ELSE Stage_Completed_Date_Time 
       END AS Suspend_Complete_Date_Time
    --INTO #SuspendedDateTime --(for inserting into a temp table)
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME 
    ;
```